# Como configurar correctamente un correo corporativo para enviar y recibir mensajes

Tags: wordpress

estoy creando mi web con wordpress y he creado un correo corporativo pero solo me permite enviar  correos y  no recibir. cuando me tratan de enviar un correo rebota y sale este error:

```
550 Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. mail-lj1- 
f178.google.com [209.85.208.178]:41979 is not permitted to relay through 
this server without authentication.
```

les agradezco mucho de su ayuda..

Comment: ¿como puedes recibir correos si ese correo que has creado solo te permite enviar? no veo como va a ser posible eso. Edita y explícate mejor para poderte ayudar. un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Estoy seguro que debes configurar tu correo en Gsuite para poder usarlo en plataforma de terceros. Revisa más información aquí: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=es